sudo, timeout, mount.cifs and systemd-ask-pass
I have a CIFS mount command I want to let users run with sudo that requires them to enter their password.  I made a script with line like this:
/usr/sbin/mount.cifs -o user=$SUDO_USER,domain=WORKGROUP //stserv.foo.com/share /mnt/share

and give users sudo on the script. This works okay as the user gets prompted for their password and then it mounts.
However I wanted to put a timeout on it so I put a timeout 10s in front of the command in the script.  Now when run through sudo it does not work. Users see the password prompt but when they type their password it appears on the terminal in plain text instead of "*****" and the command just hangs till it times out.  Then it tries to run the user's password as a command.
Look at the process tree when this is happening I see:
bash───sudo(root)───mount_sleepepi───timeout───mount.cifs───mount.cifs───systemd-ask-pas

So it appears this systemd-ask-pass is getting in the way.
Is there a way to prevent this when running under timeout.

Using timeout --foreground should allow the password entry to work, but I don't know if it will be able to kill the process after it times out.

your ask was answered in this https://askubuntu.com/a/401536

@BANJOSA  Actually, no it does not.  That is totally different issue related to the password for sudo itself.  This is about a password ask from a totally different program being run inside a script run with sudo.

@meuh This works!  And it is still able to kill the process after the timeout

Good to know. Please post an answer saying what worked for you, and you should be able to accept it (tick it) after a while.

As @meuh pointed out, the answer is to add --foreground option to the timeout command.
